# Why android video player that based on ffmpeg can't sync video' time and audio's time?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

## Background

Recently, I use ffmpeg to write my first Android video player. But video channel's time is faster than audio channel's time about 2~3 times.

## Question

Why android video player audio and video is out of sync? Video is about faster than audio 2~3 times. Thanks for your reading and answers.

## Code

In short, I use PacketDispatcher to read AVPacket from http hlv source:

```
void PacketDispatcher::RealDispatch() {
    while (GetStatus() != DISPATCHER_STOP) {
        ...

        AVPacket *av_packet = av_packet_alloc();
        int ret = av_read_frame(av_format_context, av_packet);

        // PacketDispatcher is who read the AVPacket from http hlv source 
        // and dispatch to decoder by its stream index.
        decoder_map[av_packet->stream_index]->Push(av_packet);
    }
}
```

And then, Decoder written by Producer-Consumer Pattern, Decoder maintain a queue that store all the AVPacket received from PacketDispatcher. The code like this:

```
// write to the queue
void BaseDecoder::Push(AVPacket *av_packet) {
    ...
    av_packet_queue.push(av_packet);
    ...
}

// real decode logic
void BaseDecoder::RealDecode() {
    ...
    while (true) {
        // read frame from codec
        AVFrame *av_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(av_codec_ctx, av_frame);

        void *decode_result = DecodeFrame(av_frame);
        // send to render
        m_render->Render(decode_result);
    }
}
```

And then, I do rendering logic in Render. Render also written by Producer-Consumer Pattern, it maintain a queue that store AVFrame received from Decoder, the code like this:

```
// write AVFrame
void BaseRender::Render(void *frame_data) {
    ...
    frame_queue.push(frame_data);
    ...
}

// render to surface or Open SL
void BaseRender::RealRender() {
    if (m_render_synchronizer && m_render_synchronizer->Sync(frame_data)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Finally, the synchronizer will decide to **sleep time** or **drop video frame** according to the frame pts, **frame pts is** :

```
frame_data->pts = av_frame->best_effort_timestamp * av_q2d(GetTimeBase());
```

Also, **video extra delay is**:

```
frame_data->video_extra_delay = av_frame->repeat_pict * 1.0 / fps * 2.0;
```

RenderSynchronizer code like this:

```
bool RenderSynchronizer::Sync(void *frame_data) {
    auto base_frame_data = static_cast<BaseFrameData *>(frame_data);
    if (base_frame_data->media_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        audio_pts = pcm_data->pts;
        return false;
    } else if (base_frame_data->media_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        video_pts = rgba_data->pts;
        return ReceiveVideoFrame(static_cast<RGBAData *>(frame_data));
    }
    return false;
}

bool RenderSynchronizer::ReceiveVideoFrame(RGBAData *rgba_data) {
    if (audio_pts <= 0 || video_pts <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    double diff = video_pts - audio_pts;
    if (diff > 0) {
        if (diff > 1) {
            av_usleep((unsigned int) (rgba_data->extra_delay * 1000000.0));
        } else {
            av_usleep((unsigned int) ((diff + rgba_data->extra_delay) * 1000000.0));
        }
        return false;
    } else if (diff < 0) {
        LOGD(TAG, "drop video frame");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am struggeling with the same problem. It seems that the received "pts" values differ of the video and audio stream. I have not tested with media with more than 2 streams. In my case the pts values of the audio frames starts with higher value than video pts values,

Comment: With the same "source" code on windows (delphi in my case) the pts values of video and audio frames are about the same and syncing is a less problem.